# Find, if possible, a matrix Y such that (Y + BCT)-1 = A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Here is the question

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPP5z.png)

and I am asked to "find, if possible, a matrix Y such that (Y + BCT)-1 = A"

my answer was:

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9rHU.png)

is it right? what makes me uncertain of my answer is moving matrix Q for example to the other side of the equal sign makes it (Q inverse) ? in all cases(addition and multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same question. I guess it is 
y = A - (BC-1)T